# How to access data from table in laravel 5 using jquery get or post with where condition

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-5

I am new in `laravel 5`, I want to access student list who are in class 10,

Suppose you have a student table and have all class students.

I want to pass class id using select box and then want all student list in result div using `jquery` in `laravel 5`...

Comment: I have tried the code given bellow  but found 404 error
                             
        var class_id  =   $("#class_id").val();                           
                                                                              
        $.get( "{{ url('/getAllStudent') }}", function( data ) {         
            $( "#result_id" ).html( data );                              
        });  

can i use route or i can use url only

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax call for this on selectbox change event and then create the php script for the ajax call like below

If your table name is like students with example columns call_id,student_id,name, other columns

then code should be

```
$students = DB::table('students')->where('call_id', 10)->get();
```

you can traverse the students like

```
$html = '';
foreach ($students as $student)
{
    // create your html for required fields to display
    $html = '<div> Student Name :'.$student->name.'</div>';
}
echo $html;
```

and display this returned ajax response in your target div.

you will get result

Comment: How can i find the page. i am always get 404 error, page name is getAllStudent.blade.php

jQuery.get( "{{ url('getAllStudent') }}", function( data ) {         
            jQuery( "#result_id" ).html( data );                              
 });

Comment: @GauravPandey did you defined the route in the route file?

Comment: For that in ajax url you need to write controllername/actionname, I think getAllStudent is your action name. You need to specify the controller name as well like **controllername/actionname**